# SAPUI5: Output formatted date

Tags: odata, sapui5

I´ve developed an SAPUI5 application with an XML-View.

Now I want to format a date correctly.

I tried it the following way:

```xml
 <Text text="{  
   path: 'model>LastCommDate',  
   type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',  
   formatOptions: {  
     pattern: 'yyyy/MM/dd'  
   }
 }" />
```

Error message:
`datajs.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: j.getTime is not a function`

Without the `formatOptions` and `type` I get the unformatted output.

```xml
<Text text="{  
  path: 'model>LastCommDate'
}" />
```

Output: `2015-06-16T00:00:00`

EDIT:

Same question for `Time`:
How should look the patterns for a time-object?

type: `sap.ui.model.type.Time`

Unformated output: `PT19H21M29S`

Answer (score 6):

First of all it depends on how your date is stored in the model.
If you have it as JavaScript date object, your example should work.

If you have it as a string, you need to tell the Date type how to parse the string, i.e. which format to expect. You do so by adding a `source` section to the `formatOptions`:

```xml
  <Text text="{
    path: 'model>LastCommDate',
    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
    formatOptions: {
      source: {
        pattern: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'
      },
      pattern: 'yyyy/MM/dd'
    }
  }" />
```

For a comparison of the two see [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CgffU3).