# Formatting a "/Date(timestamp)/" value in UI5

Tags: date, formatting, odata, sapui5

I have a similar question like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23537581) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36195387). I am using an XML view, too. With this code

```
<Text text="{ path: 'model1>CHANGE_DATE' }" />
```

I get the following response from the OData (V2) service:

```
/Date(1671944676355)/
```

When I try

```
<Text text="{
  path: 'model1>CHANGE_DATE', 
  type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', 
  formatOptions: { pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }
}"/>
```

I receive the error message:

> sap-ui-core-dbg.js:30928 Uncaught TypeError: oDate.getTime is not a function

Do you have any idea why the formatting did not work?

Comment: Is this an ODataModel? Is the field declared as Edm.DateTime?

Comment: Ah ok. I am using a JsonModel. Perhaps this is the reason. I can try to convert to OdataModel - if necessary.

Comment: Guess this is the reason. You could also switch to another date format or use a formatter function to convert the string to a JS Date object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to ODataModel solved this issue.